# If string does NOT contain and REGEX

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for a way to write the following javascript code in applescript: If the condition is false then I want to do something.

```
var regEx = /\d{5}/g;
var str = 'This string contains 12345';

if (!regEx.test(str)){
    do something
}
```

Below is the applescript I started but it doesn't work.

```
set str to 'This string contains 12345'
set regEx to <NOT SURE HOW APPLESCRIPT HANDLES THIS>

if string does contains "12345" then
 do something
end if
```

In Javascript ! = does not. What is the equivalent in applescript? and how do I handle RegEx?

My overall goal is to find out if the finder window selected DOES NOT contain any 5 digit number combination in the folder name.

Comment: Vanilla AppleScript can't handle regex. You could use the SatImage OSAX or `NSRegularExpression` from the Foundation framework

Comment: Thanks for that @vadian, but that is a bit much for me. Forget REGEX, how would you search a string that contains 5 digits?

Comment: You could also shell out to something that _does_ know regex, for example `set bool to (do shell script "/usr/bin/ruby -e 'puts !(\"" & str & "\" =~ /\\d{5}/).nil?'") = "true"`

Comment: Thanks @red_menace. After testing and fiddling around your suggestion acts like regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** *For any version of macOS that is `>= OSX 10.8` you'll need to replace `grep`'s `-P` option (as indicated in the **"Solution"** section below) with the `-E` option - as mentioned in the **"Different `grep` utilities"** section at the bottom of this post.*

---

As correctly noted in the comments...

> Vanilla AppleScript can't handle regex. - [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian)

so you'll need to

> shell out to something that does know regex - [red_menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10853463/red-menace)

---

### Solution:

To meet your requirement with vanilla AppleScript in a way which is analogous to JavaScript's [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method, consider utilizing a custom AppleScript subroutine as follows:

#### Subroutine:

```
on regExpTest(str, re)      
  set statusCode to do shell script "grep -q -P " & quoted form of re & ¬
    " <<<" & quoted form of str & " 2>/dev/null; echo $?"

  if statusCode is equal to "0" then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end if
end regExpTest
```

#### Usage:

```
set regExp to "\\d{5}"
set str to "This string contains 12345"

if regExpTest(str, regExp) then
  display dialog "It DOES match so let's do something"
end if
```

Running the above script will display a dialog with the given message because there is a match between the regular expression and the specified string.

<sub>**Note:** AppleScript strings use the backslash as an escape character, so you'll notice that the `\d` metacharacter has been further escaped with an additional backslash, i.e. `\\d`</sub>

#### Inequality operators:

> In Javascript `!=` does not. What is the equivalent in applescript? and how do I handle RegEx?

AppleScript's [inequality operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_operators.html) that are analogous to [JavaScripts inequality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Inequality) (`!=`) are:

```
≠
is not
isn't
isn't equal [to]
is not equal [to]
doesn't equal
does not equal
```

So given your JavaScript `if` statement:

> ```
> if (!regEx.test(str)){
>   // do something
> }
> ```

We can achieve the same logic, (again using the aforementioned custom `regExpTest` subroutine), with the following code:

```
set regExp to "\\d{5}"
set str to "This string contains 1234"

if regExpTest(str, regExp) ≠ true then
  display dialog "It DOES NOT match so let's do something"
end if
```

<sub>**Note** The `str` value only includes four consecutive digits, i.e. `1234`.</sub>

This time running the above script will display a dialog with the given message because there is *NOT* a match between the regular expression and the specified string.

There are many variations that can be made to the aforementioned AppleScript `if` statement to acheieve the same desired logic. For example;

```
if regExpTest(str, regExp) is not equal to true then
  ...
end if
```

```
if regExpTest(str, regExp) = false then
  ...
end if
```

etc...

---

### `regExpTest` subroutine explanation:

The aforementioned `regExpTest` AppleScript subroutine is essentially utilizing the [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CallCommandLineUtilities.html) command to run the following code that you would run directly via your macOS `Terminal` application. For instance in your `Terminal` application run the following two commands:

```sh
grep -q -P "\d{5}" <<<"This string contains 12345" 2>/dev/null; echo $?
```

Prints:

> `0`

```sh
grep -q -P "\d{5}" <<<"This string contains 1234" 2>/dev/null; echo $?
```

Prints:

> `1`

---

#### EDIT: Different `grep` utilities:

As noted in the comment by [user3439894](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439894/user3439894) it seems that some versions of the [grep](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html) utility installed on Mac do not support the `-P` option which ensured the RegExp pattern was interpreted as a Perl regular expression. The reason why I opted to utilize a Perl Regular Expression is because they're more closely aligned to the regexp's used in JavaScript.

However, If you run `man grep` via your command line and discover that your `grep`utility  doesn't provide the `-P` option then change the following line of code in the `regExpTest` subroutine:

```
set statusCode to do shell script "grep -q -P " & quoted form of re & ¬
  " <<<" & quoted form of str & " 2>/dev/null; echo $?"
```

to this instead:

```
set statusCode to do shell script "grep -q -E " & quoted form of re & ¬
  " <<<" & quoted form of str & " 2>/dev/null; echo $?"
```

**Note:** The `-P` option has been changed to `-E` so the pattern is now interpreted as an extended regular expression (ERE) instead.

**The shorthand metacharacter `\d`**

You may also find that you need to change the the assignment of the regexp pattern from:

```
set regExp to "\\d{5}"
```

to

```
set regExp to "[0-9]{5}"
```

This time the shorthand metacharacter `\d`, (which is used match a digit), has been replaced with the equivalent character class `[0-9]`.

Comment: In a stock **macOS**, your `grep` _command_ using the `-P` _option_ fails as that _option_ is not supported. Use the `-E` _option_ with stock **macOS** `grep` _command_. In  e.g. **macOS High Sierra** the `grep --version` _command_ returns `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`. To use the `-P` _option_, **GNU** `grep` is needed.

Comment: Thank you @RobC for the explanation as it was very thorough :-). Even though I got the do shell script suggested by red_menace, I will be testing/studying what you shared. To user3439894, thank you for your added comment.

Comment: @user3439894 - Thanks for feedback regarding compatibility - added note to answer. Out of interest did your `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` utility successfully handle the shorthand metacharacter `\d` in a ERE (i.e. with the `-E` option) - Or did you have to provide it as a character class instead, i.e. `[0-9]` ?

Comment: @RobC, Using the _command_ example you've provided, while using the `-E` _option_ instead of `-P` did work as tested, and why I suggested using it. **BSD** `grep` is the default `grep` for **macOS**, while one has to manually install **GNU** `grep` to use the `-P` _option_. BTW Nice answer! +1

Comment: Thanks @user3439894 for confirmation. I've never noticed before that Apple changed flavours of the `grep` utility. I'm currently mobile, so on an old machine running OSX - interestingly its stock `grep` is/was `GNU grep`.

Comment: @user3439894 - This old laptop that I'm currently on is _OSX 10.6.8_ and I can confirm `$ grep --version` reports `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`. BTW - it has no custom installation of other utilities - it's factory settings. Pretty sure _10.6.8_ (Snow Leopard IIRC) came after Tiger.

Comment: @RobC, Okay, **Mac OS X 10.7 Lion** was the last version to ship with **GNU** `grep` as the default and it has been **BSD** `grep` since **OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion**.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use the Foundation framework’s `NSRegularExpression` via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge.

That said, Objective-C APIs, while powerful, aren’t exactly AppleScripter-friendly, so I knocked together some [“standard libraries”](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) a few years  back that wrapped a lot of that general functionality as nice native AppleScript commands.

e.g. Here’s the nearest equivalent to your JavaScript using the `Text` library’s `search text` command:

```
use script "Text"

set str to "This string contains 12345"

set foundMatches to search text str for "\\d{5}" using pattern matching

if foundMatches is not {} then
    -- do something
end if
```

Couldn’t drum up much interest so I no longer do development or support. But they’re free and open (public domain as far as I’m concerned) and still work fine in the current version of macOS AFAIK, so help yourself.